# How to convert GL_RED to GL_RGBA format

Tags: c++, opengl

This is the code for the fragment shader.

```c
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D texture1;
out vec4 OutColor;
    
void main()
{
    OutColor = texture( texture1 , TexCoord);
}
```

Whenever any `GL_RED` format texture is passed the greyscale image outputs as red in color.

I can fix that by using the red parameter of the texture in the shader but is it possible to send GL_RED image as GL_RGBA image to the shader.

```cpp
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(file, &width, &height,  &channels , SOIL_LOAD_AUTO);  
// Set The Internal Format
if (channels == 4)
{
    texture.Internal_Format = gammaCorrect ? GL_SRGB_ALPHA : GL_RGBA;
    texture.Image_Format = gammaCorrect ? GL_SRGB_ALPHA : GL_RGBA;
}
else if(channels == 3)
{
    
    texture.Internal_Format = gammaCorrect ? GL_SRGB : GL_RGB;
    texture.Image_Format = gammaCorrect ? GL_SRGB : GL_RGB;
}
else if (channels == 1)
{
    texture.Internal_Format = GL_RED;
    texture.Image_Format = GL_RED;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the texture swizzle parameters with [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml). e.g.:

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObject);

if (channels == 1)
{
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G, GL_RED);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B, GL_RED);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_A, GL_RED);
}
```

This sets the swizzle that will be applied to a component. With that a component can be taken from a different channel.

Comment: Thank you very much , its been a long time hearing from you , Just one more question this also sets  the swizzling for other RGBA textures so how do i turn it off for other RGBA textures.

Comment: @Summit This is a texture parameter that is only applied to the currently bound texture. My answer was unclear in this point. I changed that.